# Age Calculations (First Draft)

Tags: c#, beginner, datetime

I found another user asking for an application to be written,  it sounded simple enough and a good way to "work out" my C# "muscles" and try to get them into a better "shape". I really liked the idea of learning the difference between people's ages so I decided I would code this, I did enlist the help of Stack Overflow of which I have given attribution for the code I used.

> ## Here is the original criteria
>
> ### For example:
>
> ```
> Please enter the number of siblings: 3 
> Please enter date of birth of sibling 1: 01-01-1990 
> Please enter date of birth of sibling 2: 05-03-1995
> Please enter date of birth of sibling 3: 08-05-1998 
> Age of sibling 1 is: 25 years 2 months 19 days 
> Age of sibling 2 is: 20 years 0 months 15 days 
> Age of sibling 3 is: 16 years 10 months 12 days 
> Difference between sibling 1 and 2 is: 05 years 2 months and 4 days 
> Difference between sibling 2 and 3 is: 03 years 02 months and 3 days
> ```

This is only a console application (*so far*).

I started out writing the code in Main and soon realized that I wanted some custom objects, so I first created a Human Interface (nothing special in it, yet)  which holds a simple DOB, in the future this describe other things and may possibly need to be named something else (most likely).  The Sibling Class implements the Human Interface (and not much more, yet).

#### Human.cs

```
interface Human
{
    DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}
```

#### Sibling.cs

```
class Sibling : Human
{
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public Sibling (DateTime dateOfBirth)
    {
        this.DOB = dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

I also made use of some DateTime manipulation, along with a struct of someone else's creation (it came in rather handy)

#### DateTimeExtensions.cs

```
static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static int AgeInYears (DateTime age1, DateTime age2)
    {
        return Math.Abs(age1.Year - age2.Year);
    }
    public static int AgeInMonths (DateTime age1, DateTime age2)
    {
         return ((age1.Year - age2.Year) * 12) + (age1.Month - age2.Month);
    }
    public static int AgeInDays (DateTime age1, DateTime age2)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(((age1.Year - age2.Year) * 365.25) + (age1.DayOfYear - age2.DayOfYear));
    }

    public static int AgePartYears(DateTime age1, DateTime age2)
    {
        return DateTimeSpan.CompareDates(age1, age2).Years;
    }

    public static int AgePartMonths(DateTime age1, DateTime age2)
    {
        return DateTimeSpan.CompareDates(age1, age2).Months;
    }

    public static int AgePartDays(DateTime age1, DateTime age2)
    {
        return DateTimeSpan.CompareDates(age1, age2).Days;
    }
}
```

#### DateTimeSpan Struct

<sub>*resides in DateTimeExtensions currently*</sub>

```
/// <summary>
/// http://stackoverflow.com/a/9216404/1214743
/// http://stackoverflow.com/users/189950/kirk-woll
/// answered Feb 9 '12 at 18:14
/// </summary>
public struct DateTimeSpan
{
    private readonly int years;
    private readonly int months;
    private readonly int days;
    private readonly int hours;
    private readonly int minutes;
    private readonly int seconds;
    private readonly int milliseconds;

    public DateTimeSpan(int years, int months, int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int milliseconds)
    {
        this.years = years;
        this.months = months;
        this.days = days;
        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.seconds = seconds;
        this.milliseconds = milliseconds;
    }


    public int Years { get { return years; } }
    public int Months { get { return months; } }
    public int Days { get { return days; } }
    public int Hours { get { return hours; } }
    public int Minutes { get { return minutes; } }
    public int Seconds { get { return seconds; } }
    public int Milliseconds { get { return milliseconds; } }

    enum Phase { Years, Months, Days, Done }

    public static DateTimeSpan CompareDates(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
    {
        if (date2 < date1)
        {
            var sub = date1;
            date1 = date2;
            date2 = sub;
        }

        DateTime current = date1;
        int years = 0;
        int months = 0;
        int days = 0;

        Phase phase = Phase.Years;
        DateTimeSpan span = new DateTimeSpan();

        while (phase != Phase.Done)
        {
            switch (phase)
            {
                case Phase.Years:
                    if (current.AddYears(years + 1) > date2)
                    {
                        phase = Phase.Months;
                        current = current.AddYears(years);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        years++;
                    }
                    break;
                case Phase.Months:
                    if (current.AddMonths(months + 1) > date2)
                    {
                        phase = Phase.Days;
                        current = current.AddMonths(months);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        months++;
                    }
                    break;
                case Phase.Days:
                    if (current.AddDays(days + 1) > date2)
                    {
                        current = current.AddDays(days);
                        var timespan = date2 - current;
                        span = new DateTimeSpan(years, months, days, timespan.Hours, timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds, timespan.Milliseconds);
                        phase = Phase.Done;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        days++;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return span;
    }
}
```

I haven't really dove into the Struct yet to see if there was anything that I could make better,  I really want to create some unit tests so that I don't have to run the code every time I want to test something in the code.

and last but not least, the ugliest part of any application the Main.

#### Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of siblings");
    var siblingCount = new int();
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out siblingCount);
    var siblings = new List<Sibling>();
    for (int i = 1; i < siblingCount + 1; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Please Enter the date of birth for sibling " + i.ToString() + ":");
        siblings.Add(new Sibling(DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine())));
    }
    siblings = siblings.OrderByDescending(x => x.DOB).ToList();

    for (int i = 1; i < siblings.Count + 1; i++)
    {
        var diff = DateTimeSpan.CompareDates(siblings[i - 1].DOB, DateTime.Now);
        Console.WriteLine("Age of sibling " + i + " is: " + diff.Years + " years, " + diff.Months + " months and " + diff.Days + " days.");
    }

    for (var i = 1; i < siblingCount; i++)
    {
        var diff = DateTimeSpan.CompareDates(siblings[i - 1].DOB, siblings[i].DOB);
        Console.WriteLine("Difference between sibling " + i.ToString() + " and " + (i + 1).ToString() + " is " +
            diff.Years + " years, " + diff.Months + " months and " + diff.Days + " days.");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

- What do you think?
- How can I clean up the `Console.WriteLine()`'s all over the place?
- I know that the next step is exception handling, is my code supportive of this next step?
- Is there anything that I could do to get my code ready for unit testing?

Comment: Make sure your unit tests cover leap years.

Comment: I don't think you need `DateTimeSpan` at all. Converting time differences from one format to another isn't that difficult.

Comment: I look forward to the Review, @BarryCarter.

Comment: Are you going to tweak it based on @Johan_Larsson's review, or should I review it (or more likely rewrite it) as is?

Comment: when I make changes I will post the new code for review, I have other things that I want to do as well, like unit testing and exception handling and such.  when it comes to Reviews, the More the Merrier.

Comment: Why Human.cs ? I want to calculate ages of my cats :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Human.cs**

- Why is there a set method? I don't expect date of birth to change. This is a big deal, state and data are very different things. Always default to making things immutable/readonly.
- I don't like `DOB`, use `DateOfBirth` here. A good rule of thumb is that length of names should be proportional to scope. As a variable in a method `dob` may be fine, as a member in a public interface not so much.
- The convention in C# is naming interfaces `IHuman`. `IDateOfBirth` may be a better name btw.
- Good that the interface is minimal, this will allow for it to be used on things like `public class Dog : IDateOfBirth`

**Sibling.cs**

- Given we make date of birth readonly we can add some validation (if it makes sense in your application):

  ```
  internal class Sibling : IDateOfBirth
  {
      public Sibling(DateTime dateOfBirth)
      {
          if (dateOfBirth > DateTime.UtcNow)
          {
              throw new ArgumentException("Date of birth cannot be in the future", nameof(dateOfBirth));
          }

          if (dateOfBirth < DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-150))
          {
              throw new ArgumentException("Date of birth must be less than 150 years from now", nameof(dateOfBirth));
          }

          this.DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
      }

      public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; }
  }
  ```

  - The convention in C# is to specify the internal explicitly. Not important, just mentioning it.

**DateTimeSpan.cs**

- Good that you link the source in a comment.
- With C#6 you can clean it up using get only properties. Nothing wrong with public readonly fields either, might be controversial idk.
- Skipping the rest of the code from the SO answer.

**Program.cs**

- `var siblingCount = new int();` use `var siblingCount = 0;` as it reads clearer.
- You may want to handle the case where the user inputs an illegal number. `int.TryParse() returns a bool so you can do:

  ```
  if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out siblingCount))
  {
      // handle invalid input
  }
  ```
- Avoid concatenating strings with +. With C#6 you can use string interpolation like this:

  ```
  for (var i = 0; i < siblingCount; i++)
  {
      Console.Write($"Please Enter the date of birth for sibling {i + 1}:");
      var line = Console.ReadLine();
      DateTime dateOfBirth;
      if (!DateTime.TryParse(line, out dateOfBirth))
      {
          // handle invalid input
      }

      siblings.Add(new Sibling(dateOfBirth));
  }
  ```

- DateTime has [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) and [TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) which may be a better fit for this. Parse will crash your program with a `FormatException`if user inputs an invalid date.
- Storing `var line = Console.ReadLine();` in a variable is nice for debugging.

- Prefer to loop over the collection

  ```
  for (var i = 0; i < siblings.Count; i++)
  {
      var sibling = siblings[i];
      var diff = DateTimeSpan.CompareDates(sibling.DateOfBirth, DateTime.Now);
      Console.WriteLine($"Age of sibling {i + 1} is: {diff.Years} years, {diff.Months} months and {diff.Days} days.");
  }
  ```

**Testing**

- The logic in `DateTimeExtensions` and `DateTimeSpan`is very easy to test.

**Summary**

The public set for date of birth is the biggest issue with this code.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review this code, I will check it out in more detail when I get back to my machine.